# Is it possible to upgrade to OpenGL 4 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, hardware, opengl

I need OpenGL 4.0+ to play a game.

I have an Intel i7-4770S. According to the [manufacturer page](http://ark.intel.com/products/75124/Intel-Core-i7-4770S-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) for my driver + integrated graphics, it supports up to OpenGL 4.3.

However, when I run

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

I get:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
```

I understand that Ubuntu 16.04 includes OpenGL 4, but I'm trying to avoid having to upgrade for the time being. (The auto upgrader wouldn't work because of unsupported packages and I don't want to do a full reinstall at the moment.)

So, is there a way that I can get to OpenGL 4 while still on 14.04? (And if not, is it certain that I'll have OpenGL 4 support for my processor in 16.04?)

Thanks!

Comment: That's not the correct version you're looking at. What does the "core profile vrsion string" say in `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` output?

Comment: Ah thanks. Bad advice from Googling. "core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3"

Answer (score 1):

The version of Mesa on the version of 14.04 you're using only supports up to OpenGL 3.3 on the Intel graphics driver. You will need to upgrade to either a newer HWE (14.04.5 HWE has same kernel/Xorg as 16.04 does), or to 16.04, to get newer Mesa which supports higher versions of OpenGL.

If you install the `xserver-xorg-lts-xenial` and `linux-generic-lts-xenial` packages, this should put you on the 14.04.5 HWE kernel and Xorg, after a successful install and reboot. Depending on what additional packages you've installed, you may hit some bumps and need to manually install more packages to resolve dependency errors.

Comment: Got this result when i ran that command: http://pastebin.com/pxKp2sBu

Comment: I figured out how to install those packages. It upgraded Mesa to 11.2.0 but my core profile version string was still 3.3. I'm guessing that means openGL 4 isn't supported for my card yet? Not sure why that would be the case if the Intel website says it's supported. But I can make another question for that. Went ahead and did the full 16.04 fresh install and had the same core profile result. Would install the oaibf ppa help me at this point or no?